# Entity Framework Core foreign key problem with IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a new entry in my database with EF Core like this:

```
RefreshToken newDBRefreshToken = new RefreshToken()
{
    Id = 0,
    Token = refreshToken,
    AccessToken = accessToken,
    UserId = userId
};

_dbContext.RefreshToken.Add(newDBRefreshToken);
```

I get this error message upon saving:

> The foreign key '{UserId: 5b82dbb0-c38b-4144-b51d-e092ef6f5e55}' set
>   on 'RefreshToken' with the key value '{Id: -2147482647}' matches an
>   entity of type 'IdentityUser', however the principal entity type
>   should be assignable to 'ApplicationUser'.

I have two Entities:

```
//To make it possible to use AspNetUsers as a reference table
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class RefreshToken : BaseEntity //Has int Id and CreateDate ect...
{
    //Reference the IdentityUser
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }
}
```

the migration created my RefreshToken table like this:
[image]

Edit:
This is my Startup.cs section:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connection, builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).Assembly.FullName)
 ).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true));

// ===== Add Identity ========
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<IdentityErrorDescriberDE>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I tried using `ApplicationUser` as TUser, which gives me this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   while attempting to activate 'Web.Controllers.AccountController'.

This is my Context:

```
public class ApiContext : IdentityDbContext {
...
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to say without being able to see your context and/or startup, but in one of the two you've referenced `IdentityUser` as the `TUser` type param to something that takes that. `IdentityDbContext` has versions that take generic type params to specify implementations of domain types. You need to make sure it's using *your* entity, i.e. `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` not `IdentityDbDontext<IdentityUser>`. Also, in startup, you should have something like `AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()`, not `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()`.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. Didn't work. AddDefaultIdentity is not available. What am I missing? :/

Comment: You need to change your `_Login` partial, which injects `UserManager<IdentityUser>` and `SignInManager<IdentityUser>` by default. Change both of those instances to `ApplicationUser` as well.

Comment: Hey thanks. Yeah you're right! It's working now :)

Comment: Just FYI: what was actually happening was because you had `IdentityUser` as the `TUser` type param, it was making that the base user entity, and then since `ApplicationUser` inherited from that, it was setting up a single table inheritance structure with a discriminator column. You were creating users as `IdentityUser` instances and then attempting associate them as `ApplicationUser` instances, which they were not. The changes you made caused `ApplicationUser` to be *the* user, so the association works fine then.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :) Really appreciate it!